# Reference request: infinitely nested radicals.

Tags: reference-request, radicals, nested-radicals

I am requesting a reference to books, digital or print, that discuss nested radicals/infinitely nested radicals. There doesn't seem to be a go-to book for nested radicals as Khinchin's *Continued Fractions* is to continued fractions. I am primarily interested in texts discussing nested radicals in theory, not in application.

Comment: I second this post (+1)

Comment: @clathratus: I don't know of a book that's similar to Khinchin's book (or, in fact, of any book that is essentially devoted to continued radicals), but the following manuscript gives a very detailed and thorough survey of the literature on continued radicals: [*A chronology of continued square roots and other continued compositions, through the year 2016*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06139.pdf) by Dixon J. Jones (17 July 2017; revised 15 June 2018).